# spam email sent from my exchange account but not in my sent items

Tags: exchange, spam-prevention, outlook-web-access

we have an issue where we are receiving emails from contacts that they have received emails from our users that contain dangerous links in the email.

The email being sent is from a previous email chain between our user and the external contact.

The email is not in the our users sent items.

When we look at the header of the email being sent it seems like the email is coming from our network but we cant workout how they are doing it.

I suspect that they are using OWA to send the emails so is there a way we can find out what email account they are using to access the mail server and send these emails and why are they not in the sent items of the users account?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using DKIM and DMARC ? Its the only way to prevent email spoofing

Comment: If they get yours or others email list, they can spoof them.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your exchange server?

Have you installed the security updates on exchange server? [Released: November 2021 Exchange Server Security Updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/released-november-2021-exchange-server-security-updates/ba-p/2933169)

Could you enable the mailbox audit log? If you have enabled it, you could check the audit log. For more details: [Mailbox audit logging in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mailbox-audit-logging/mailbox-audit-logging?view=exchserver-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is some malware in your network and sending emails in the background (e.x. telnet).
You can try sniff with [whireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) from server all the SMTP connection to figure out what is going on.